# Synchronizing method calls on shared object from multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I am thinking about how to implement a class that will contain private data that will be eventually be modified by multiple threads through method calls. For synchronization (using the Windows API), I am planning on using a `CRITICAL_SECTION` object since all the threads will spawn from the same process.

Given the following design, I have a few questions.

```
template <typename T> class Shareable
{
private:
    const LPCRITICAL_SECTION sync; //Can be read and used by multiple threads
    T *data;
public:
    Shareable(LPCRITICAL_SECTION cs, unsigned elems) : sync{cs}, data{new T[elems]} { }
    ~Shareable() { delete[] data; }
    void sharedModify(unsigned index, T &datum) //<-- Can this be validly called
    //by multiple threads with synchronization being implicit?
    {
        EnterCriticalSection(sync);
        /*
            The critical section of code involving reads & writes to 'data'
        */
        LeaveCriticalSection(sync);
    }
};

// Somewhere else ...

DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    Shareable<ActualType> *ptr = static_cast<Shareable<ActualType>*>(lpParameter);
    T copyable = /* initialization */;
    ptr->sharedModify(validIndex, copyable); //<-- OK, synchronized?
    return 0;
}
```

The way I see it, the API calls will be conducted in the context of the current thread. That is, I assume this is the same as if I had acquired the critical section object from the pointer and called the API from within `ThreadProc()`. However, I am worried that if the object is created and placed in the main/initial thread, there will be something funky about the API calls.

1. When `sharedModify()` is called *on the same object* concurrently,
   from multiple threads, will the synchronization be implicit, in the
   way I described it above?
2. Should I instead get a pointer to the
   critical section object and use that instead?
3. Is there some other
   synchronization mechanism that is better suited to this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When `sharedModify()` is called *on the same object* concurrently, from multiple threads, will the synchronization be implicit, in the way I described it above?

Implicit from the caller's perspective, yes.

> Should I instead get a pointer to the critical section object and use that instead?

No.  In fact, I would suggest giving the `Sharable` object ownership of its own critical section instead of accepting one from the outside (and embrace RAII concepts to write safer code), eg:

```
template <typename T>
class Shareable
{
private:
    CRITICAL_SECTION sync;
    std::vector<T> data;

    struct SyncLocker
    {
        CRITICAL_SECTION &sync;
        SyncLocker(CRITICAL_SECTION &cs) : sync(cs) { EnterCriticalSection(&sync); }
        ~SyncLocker() { LeaveCriticalSection(&sync); }
    }

public:
    Shareable(unsigned elems) : data(elems)
    {
        InitializeCriticalSection(&sync);
    }

    Shareable(const Shareable&) = delete;
    Shareable(Shareable&&) = delete;

    ~Shareable()
    {
        {
        SyncLocker lock(sync);
        data.clear();
        }
        DeleteCriticalSection(&sync);
    }

    void sharedModify(unsigned index, const T &datum)
    {
        SyncLocker lock(sync);
        data[index] = datum;
    }

    Shareable& operator=(const Shareable&) = delete;
    Shareable& operator=(Shareable&&) = delete;
};
```

> Is there some other synchronization mechanism that is better suited to this scenario?

That depends.  Will multiple threads be accessing the *same* index at the same time?  If not, then there is not really a need for the critical section at all.  One thread can safely access one index while another thread accesses a different index.

If multiple threads need to access the same index at the same time, a critical section might still not be the best choice.  Locking the *entire* array might be a big bottleneck if you only need to lock *portions* of the array at a time.  Things like the Interlocked API, or Slim Read/Write locks, might make more sense.  It really depends on your thread designs and what you are actually trying to protect.

Answer (score 2):

> When sharedModify() is called on the same object concurrently, from multiple threads, will the synchronization be implicit, in the way I described it above?

It's not implicit, it's explicit. There's only only `CRITICAL_SECTION` and only one thread can hold it at a time.

> Should I instead get a pointer to the critical section object and use that instead?

No. There's no reason to use a pointer here.

> Is there some other synchronization mechanism that is better suited to this scenario?

It's hard to say without seeing more code, but this is definitely the "default" solution. It's like a singly-linked list -- you learn it first, it always works, but it's not always the best choice.